# Correctly parsing a response from YouTube API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube, youtube-api

I'm building a sample application with YouTube API (v3), that would provide a list of videos based on a search term. The concept is to populate the page using the data from the response.

I have used the client library documented in v3 to access the API, and send my request, however I don't know how to properly navigate through the data provided in the response in order to display the desired elements. The code below shows my script, where I am trying to access and list the title of the videos in the response:

```
 $(function () {
    //FUNCTION TO COLLECT QUERY TERM FROM SEARCH FORM
     var $searchField = $('#search-text');

    $('#mainSearch'). on ('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($searchField.val() !== '') { //IF SEARCH FORM IS NOT EMPTY
                var $searchQuery = $searchField.val()+ ' parody'; //PREPARE SEARCH QUERY
                makeRequest($searchQuery);  //PASS SEARCH QUERY TO REQUEST FUNCTION
            }
            else {
                $searchField.focus(); //ADD ERROR CLASS HERE
                $searchField.blur(function (e){
                    //REMOVE ERROR CLASS HERE
            });

        }
    });

    function makeRequest(query){
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: 'snippet',
            q: query
        });
        $('.content').empty();
        request.execute(parseResponse);
    }

    function parseResponse(data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, items){
            var $infoDiv = $('<div></div>');
            $infoDiv.append('<p>'+ items.snippet.title +'</p>');
            $('.content').append($infoDiv);
        });
    }

});

//LOAD API CLIENT
function initClient() {
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3');
        gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyARVmOp3tBIA3ZgW6z4DK_-1sMJwulPvps');
}
```

However my page does get not populated with any data, and I get this error in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

And here is the markup for my page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Parrdy Template</title>
    <!--
    <Bootstrap></Bootstrap>-->
    <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="stylesheets/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!--
    <HTML5>Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries </HTML5>--><!--
    <WARNING>
      <Respond class="js">doesn't work if you view the page via file:// </Respond>
    </WARNING>--><!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <img src="/images/Logo1_mod.png" width="200">
        <form role="form" id= "mainSearch" class="navbar-form navbar-right pull-right">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id="vid-search" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      {{{body}}}

      <div class="footer">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left">
            <li><a class="customcolor" href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="customcolor" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div><!--container ends-->
    <!--
    <jQuery>(necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) </jQuery>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!--
    <Include>all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed</Include>-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/core1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initClient" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help on how to access the elements correctly from a YouTube API response would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Was the request succesful? Did you try to output the response?

Comment: The request was successful, and I did try to output the response on the page with no luck

Comment: Could add at the top of the parseResponse() console.log(data); ?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you'll want to keep in mind is that the stuff you are after is nested in the response as data so you need to access 'response.data' and within that data is an array of items. You'll want to access the first array with items[0] now you can grab the id from here or go deeper with `.snippet` or `.statistic`

```
get(url)
.then(response => {
id: response.DATA.items[0].id
title: response.DATA.items[0].snippet.title
}
.catch(
error => {console.log(error)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your loop like this:

```
   $.each(data.videos, function (i, items){
            var $infoDiv = $('<div></div>');
            $infoDiv.append('<p>'+ items.snippet.title +'</p>');
            $('.content').append($infoDiv);
    });
```